# get file name when using writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, alassetslibrary

in an ios swift application,
I am using `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` to save a UIImage on the iphone

```
let assets : ALAssetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
let imgRef : CGImage = myImage!.CGImage
let orientation : ALAssetOrientation = ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: myImage!.imageOrientation.rawValue)!
assets.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(imgRef, orientation: orientation, completionBlock: nil)
```

Is there a way I can get the saved image filename? or maybe to set it myself?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why are you passing nil in completion block ? Use that, then you'll get what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the spec of the method you're using you will see that the completion block you aren't using is of type `ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock`, which has the parameters `NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error`.

So specify a completion block and you get the asset URL from which you can derive some information.

Comment: Thank you for your replay but using that I get: `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=7DCF9B2E-F33D-4317-B522-5BA8E0517638&ext=JPG` while on the iphone the image name is "IMG_0027.JPG" how can I get the real name from that URL?

Comment: You can't, the URL is the closest you can get

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file path information using the completion block parameter. Instead of passing `nil` pass the block like:

```
assets.writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(imgRef, orientation: orientation, completionBlock:
{ (path:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        println("\(path)")
})
```

Check the [ALAssetLibrary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:) for more information

Comment: Thank you for your replay but using that I get: `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=7DCF9B2E-F33D-4317-B522-5BA8E0517638&ext=JPG` while on the iphone the image name is "IMG_0027.JPG" how can I get the real name from that URL?

Comment: @Youssef: Unfortunately there is no way to get that information. Probably this `7DCF9B2E-F33D-4317-B522-5BA8E0517638.JPG` will be the file name. Extract it from the url